# Как определить, к какому тегу относится текст?

Tags: машинное-обучение, nlp, искусственный-интеллект

У меня есть список тегов, например "C++", "Природа", "Еда", "Архитектура", "Писательство", "Автомобилестроение". Как определить с помощью нейросети, к какому тегу относится текст, например "Мне нравится писать на Qt"? Можно ли сделать это с помощью BERT? И какие NLP и алгоритмы под это подходят?